# Removing a created function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written this code by using some basics. I simply wanted to remove the image that I have created by using the function `Generate()` by a button. I have written the following code to remove the image generated. Please help me.
Please note that I have linked my button with the function `Reset1()`. Can someone give me the code to do the following please.

```
    function Generate()
{
    var image=document.createElement('img');
    var div=document.getElementById('flex-box-gen');
    image.src="https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif&size=small"
    div.appendChild(image);
}

function Reset1()
{
    document.getElementById('Generate').remove();
}
```

Comment: You never give the image the ID `Generate` (`img.id = 'Generate'`), so you can't find it by that ID!

Comment: Your code says nothing about an element with `id="Generate"`. Are you sure you have such an element?

Answer (score 0):

You could either assign an `id` to your image element and use that to remove in your second function:

```js
function generate() {
    var image=document.createElement("img");
    image.id = "image-01";
    ...
}

function reset() {
    var image = document.getElementById("image-01");
    var parent = image.parentNode;

    parent.removeChild(image);
}
```

Or if there is nothing else in your containing `div` element you could just empty all elements from it:

```js
function reset() {
    document.getElementById("flex-box-gen").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` will query a DOM element, not a javascript element.

What you can do, supposing you have only one `img` in your `flex-box-gen` is:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#flex-box-gen img')
if(imgs.length > 0){
  imgs[0].remove();
}
```

With a null-check in case the image was already removed

Answer (score 0):

```
image.setAttribute('id',"Generate");
```

Add this line in generate function.